# Using anchor link for form submission

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, anchor, form-submit

Can i use an anchor tag to submit a form? In this code i am using a submit button which is standard but how to use a anchor tag `<a href=Cart?removeId=${cartItem.productId>Remove</a>`

I tried this, but the doGet() method is being called in the servlet. I want to call the doPost() method obviously. So could i use a better approach.

```
<c:forEach items="${lstCart}" var="cartItem" varStatus="count">
    <form action="Cart" method=Post>
    <tr height="40px">

        <td>${count.count}</td>
        <td>${cartItem.productName}</td>
        <td>${cartItem.quantity}</td>   
        <td>${cartItem.unitPrice}</td>
        <td>${cartItem.totalPrice}</td>    
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${cartItem.productId}" />
        <input type=submit value="x"></td>

    </tr>
    </form>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use JavaScript to make an anchor link do a post. You might use CSS to style your submit button and make it look more like a link, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yep as @JB said you can post the form using JScript. One example that comes to my mind is below with struts, here you are actually passing the product id as a variable to JS method (I changed the names so it matches your example).

```
<a href="#" onclick="removeProduct(${cartItem.productId})">
Remove
</a>
```

You can then have JS method to be

```
function removeProduct(productId) {
document.forms["formname"].elements["productId"].value =
productId;
document.forms["formname"].submitTestPost.click(); 
}
```

This also assumes the following is defined in the page (so JS can set it) and the submit property (tag SubmitTag). I am not sure in your case the setup but perhaps you can draw some points.

```
<input type="hidden" name="productId"/>
```